# Tweepy streaming is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, tweepy

I'm trying to get twitter data for my thesis with Tweepy and python. When streaming with tweepy, tweets come in very slow. Is there any other library or method to do it faster? I can now read 20 tweets in 5 minutes +-. 
My code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Return API with authentication:
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


#vul variabelen in:
topic = "GOOGL"

language = "en"
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Tweets','Date','Likes','RTs','Sentiment','User','Followers'])
dfh = dataframeHandler(df)
twh = twitterHandler()

def preprocess2(raw_text):
stopword_set = set(stopwords.words("english"))
return " ".join([i for i in re.sub(r"http\S+|@\S+", "", raw_text).lower().split() if i not in stopword_set])

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
def __init__(self):
    super(CustomStreamListener, self).__init__()
    self.num_tweets = 0

def on_status(self, status):
    self.num_tweets += 1
    if self.num_tweets < 25:
        print("in")
        if not status.retweeted and 'RT @' not in status.text:
            print(status.text)
            status.text = preprocess2(status.text)
            #add tweet to df
            df.loc[len(df)] = [status.text,status.author.created_at,status.favorite_count,status.retweet_count,twh.get_tweet_sentiment(status.text),twh.get_user(status.author),twh.get_user_followers(status.user)]

            return True
    else:
        return False
def on_error(self, status_code):
    return True # Don't kill the stream

def on_timeout(self):
    print("timeout")
    return True # Don't kill the stream

myStreamListener = CustomStreamListener()

myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=CustomStreamListener())
myStream.filter(track=['AAPL'])

dfh.df.to_csv(topic + ".csv")
```